# Troubleshoot Session Timeout Issues in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I'm having issues with session timeout issues with a public facing site that is utilized by several clients that may have various "secured" browser configurations.  In general we have the session timeout set for 15 mins within the web.config.  However, they are getting a timeout within a min or within 30 seconds or so for every page postback.  Within our environment and with some other clients they have no issues and the timeout occurs as expected.  We are unable to access their systems and know very little about their infrastructure.  The only thing I'm thinking is they may have configuration to disallow cookies or delete/wipe them every few seconds etc.  Not sure....

I'm at a loss on what to look at as within our web.config we set our sessionstate as follows.

```
<sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="UseCookies" mode="InProc" sqlConnectionString="somestring Integrated Security=SSPI;pooling=true;encrypt=true;trustservercertificate=true" timeout="15">
```

If someone has ideas on where to look.

Comment: *"The only thing I'm thinking is they may have configuration to disallow cookies"* - If your application requires cookies then that's certainly worth asking the client if that's an issue for them.  You can also add logging to your web server/application to see if/what cookies are being sent by the browser.

Comment: Gee, you sure of the setup, then next sentence you state "We are un-able to access their systems"? So, which is it, you have an idea, can test and check their systems, or you can't? Regardless, session loss OFTEN means that a code error occurred (un-handled error), and that will re-set their app pool, and if that occurs, then session is lost. If not already, then I would STRONG suggest you turn on and enable SQL server based sessions.  That way, session()( becomes like a un-stoppable fright train, and will not be re-set by some stray code errors on the site.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, these are external public site visitors.  So when I mean "We are unable to access their systems", of course we can't.  The code section in my OP indicates it's using SQL based sessions.

Comment: Sure, no question, attempting to re-produce customer issues is a huge challenge. It's all so often easy when you talking about desktop programs + code, since then you can often 100% reproduce the environment and errors. With web based, you not at the customers desk, and worse their browser might be old, out of date, or really messed up, and thus you can't not only see what is going on, worse is you can't control THEIR environment either. If you have sql session based, then that should be bullet proof.

Comment: I been fighting with a bunch of ajax calls, and issues on one page. I never really found the issue (I think it was some routines doing ajax calls, and then some of those routines ALSO doing ajax calls. I finally moved the code to server side, used session(), and my issues went away. So, I assume you noting a session problem, not say client side values and js code. However, that sql session setting? I don't believe it should have the "mode="inproc", as that suggests the session system will ignore using sql server based sessions.  mode should be ---- mode="SQLServer", and NOT "inproc".

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, thanks I'm still researching that line more and I'll give that a try.